# Linux at USB HDD: should I install it as persistent?

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, persistence

I want to install Linux on external USB hard drive. Should I install it like at flash-drive, i.e. with persistent mode enabled?

HDD: 1 TB, USB 3.0 but I'm likely to use it with 2.0 because my PC doesn't support 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Just install it normally, but make sure the installation refers to the partitions by UUID (when using it later, there is no guarantee it'll get the same drive device).